# java client server multithreaded, works for only one connection

Tags: java, client-server

I did my client-server application but at the moment only one user can use it. Could you help me how to make it working for more than one user. I have the following functionality: On every two minutes counter is starting to decrease. Every user have 30 seconds to connect to the application. Every connected user should see same result with which he should make some other actions. I made it by this way at the moment. The code in the different cases is not so important. I need an advice how to make it working as a structure of the code. Thanks in advance!

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MultiServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        boolean listening = true;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 4444.");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        while (listening)
        new MultiServerThread(serverSocket.accept()).start();

        serverSocket.close();
    }
}




import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MultiServerThread extends Thread {
    private Socket socket = null;

    public MultiServerThread(Socket socket) {
        super("MultiServerThread");
    this.socket = socket;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {

            ObjectOutputStream toServer = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            ObjectInputStream fromServer = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            int userProcess = 0;
            Object data = 11111;
            boolean listening = true;


            CountDown c = new CountDown();
            int timeRemaining = 900;

            while (listening) {
                boolean send = true;
                Object ob;
                try {
                    ob = fromServer.readObject();
                    userProcess = Integer.parseInt(ob.toString());
                    HashMap<String,Integer> finalScores = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
                    if(userProcess == 0) {
                        timeRemaining = c.getRemainingTime();
                        int temp = 999;
                        while(timeRemaining-110>0) {
                            timeRemaining = c.getRemainingTime();
                            if(temp != timeRemaining) {
                                toServer.writeObject(timeRemaining-110);
                                toServer.flush();
                                temp = timeRemaining;
                            }
                        } 
                    } 
                    if(userProcess == 0 && timeRemaining-110 < 0) {
                        c = new CountDown();
                        send = false;
                    }

                    if(userProcess == 1) {   
                        BoardGeneraor board = new BoardGeneraor();
                        data = board.getBoard();
                    } 
                    if(userProcess == 2) {   
                        int score = (Integer)fromServer.readObject();
                        String username = (String)fromServer.readObject();
                        finalScores.put(username, score);
                        data = finalScores;
                        c = new CountDown();
                    }
                    if(send) {
                       toServer.writeObject(data);
                        toServer.flush();
                    } else {
                        toServer.writeObject("quit");
                        toServer.flush();
                    }
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }

            fromServer.close();
            toServer.close();
            socket.close(); 

        } catch(IOException e) {
             System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "only one user can use it" mean?

Comment: When I run my application in eclipse I can test it but when I run it second time the information which I received is different. It must be same for every user.

Comment: So I need en example for the following simple case. The server sends generated by other class string to every connected user. Every user see this same string, not different. Then every user sends different string to the server and the server saves all of the strings in maybe List.

Comment: What do you mean with *when I run it second time the information which I received is different*. Your main method always starts a new server, so of course you would see different results. You need to start one server and multiple clients to test this

Comment: I don't see any client code at all, as matter of fact, i see a server listening to itself?

Comment: As far as I understood the problem, what you should be doing is to save the `Socket` in an `ArrayList` then iterate on that `ArrayList` to send the info back to the respective Client. Since you using only one `Socket` hence the one attached latest will able to send and receive to and from the Server.

Comment: Thanks but could you send me some example because I am not sure that I can do it. This is my first client-server application and I have a lot of problems to understand what exactly should I do.

Comment: If you wanted more on the topic, take a look at this [Project](http://gagandeepbali.uk.to/gaganisonline/messenger.zip) of mine, watch the `Server.java` file. For the rest You are MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)

Comment: @user1107922 : To start client write this `java edu.gagan.messenger.client.StartClient` from classes Folder, and for Server write `java edu.gagan.messenger.server.StartServer` from server Folder , hope this might will help in some way :-) You can run multiple instances of Client and see how the server responds to each one of them.

Comment: Here is a good sample of how to code a Multi-Threadened Client-Server application, in this case, a chat server. http://www.nakov.com/books/inetjava/source-code-html/Chapter-1-Sockets/1.4.2-NakovChatServer/NakovChatServer.java.html

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you have confused the server and client and have put the client and server code within the same Java file. It looks like you intend `MultiServerThread` to be the client, since it interprets the socket's output stream as going "to server" and the socket's input stream as coming "from server." But when you create a `MultiServerThread` with `serverSocket.accept()`, you're giving it a socket that represents the *server's side of the connection* to one client. Thus the output stream returned by `socket.getOutputStream()` represents a stream from the server *to the client*. What `MultiServerThread` should actually represent is one instance of the server talking to a client, not one instance of a client connecting to the server.

In order to have clients connect to your server, you'll need a separate Java file, say Client.java, containing a separate class with a separate main method. This class should open a connection to the server with the `Socket(String host, int port)` constructor, and treat the input stream of that socket as a stream of input from the server. Here's a simple example:

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Socket serverConnection = null;

        try {
            serverConnection = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not connect to server");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        try {
            ObjecttInputStream fromServer = new ObjectInputStream(serverConnection.getInputStream());
            Object ob = fromServer.readObject();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error reading from server");
        }

    }

}
```

Once you've started your server by running the MultiServer.class file, you can start a client by running the Client.class file (in a separate window, while the server is still running).